# Android setting Condition in onCheckedChanged

Tags: android

I am displaying images from the gallery to my custom grid view with checkbox.
I have to select 6 images only.

I have the following code

```
public class MultiPhotoSelectActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> imageUrls;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    CheckBox mCheckBox;
    int pos;
    ArrayList<String> selectedItems;
    ArrayList<String> selectedimgs = new ArrayList<String>();
    RelativeLayout rl_gallery_row,rl_gallery_async;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_grid);

        //Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        //imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
        rl_gallery_async = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout_galleryas);
        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy + " DESC");

        this.imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            imageUrls.add(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));

            System.out.println("=====> Array path => "+imageUrls.get(i));
        }


        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .build();

        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imageUrls);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        /*gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                startImageGalleryActivity(position);
            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        imageLoader.stop();
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void btnChoosePhotosClick(View v){

        selectedItems = imageAdapter.getCheckedItems();
        Toast.makeText(MultiPhotoSelectActivity.this, "Total photos selected: "+selectedItems.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(MultiPhotoSelectActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Selected Items: " + selectedItems.toString());
    }


    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<String> mList;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        Context mContext;
        SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageList) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mContext = context;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
            mList = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.mList = imageList;

        }

        public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
            ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=0;i<mList.size();i++) {
                if(mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                    mTempArry.add(mList.get(i));
                }
            }

            return mTempArry;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageUrls.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            pos = position;
            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_multiphoto_item, null);
            }

            mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            rl_gallery_row = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Relativelayout_gallery_row);

            imageLoader.displayImage("file://"+imageUrls.get(position), imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MultiPhotoSelectActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                    imageView.setAnimation(anim);
                    anim.start();
                }
            });

            mCheckBox.setTag(position);
            //mCheckBox.setId(position);
            mCheckBox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
            mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);

            //mCheckBox.setId(position);
            //holder.imageview.setId(position);
            return convertView;
        }

        OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
                selectedItems = imageAdapter.getCheckedItems();
                if(selectedItems.size() > 5 )
                {
                    mCheckBox.setEnabled(false); // disable checkbox 
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now i am not able to uncheck the checkbox automatically when the limit is crossed..
Please help..

Answer (score 0):

I think your condition is not satisfied for unchecking the check box, try to put a toast inside your condition

Comment: yes the toast message is working properly..i am also able to get the number of images selected..My question is how to uncheck the checkbox when the limit is crossed(Limit here is 5)

Comment: After the limit crossed the checkbox is still enabled..its not getting disabled..setting id for check box also not working.

Comment: Try to use either of these

                mCheckBox.toggle();
or                mCheckBox.setChecked(false);